# Method missing 'type' problem with Webrat and Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, webrat

I was working on some project using webrat and cucumber (rails 3), so I created a feature with this command

```
rails g cucumber:feature Requeriment client:string realization:date hour:string shipping_company:string booking:string destiny:string rtype:string
```

Then my feature is like this

```
 Scenario: Delete requeriment
    Given the following requeriments:
      |client|realization|hour|shipping_company|booking|destiny|rtype|
      |client 1|20/01/2011|08:30|shipping_company 1|booking 1|destiny 1|rtype 1|
      |client 2|20/01/2011|08:30|shipping_company 2|booking 2|destiny 2|rtype 2|
      |client 3|20/01/2011|08:30|shipping_company 3|booking 3|destiny 3|rtype 3|
      |client 4|20/01/2011|08:30|shipping_company 4|booking 4|destiny 4|rtype 4|
    When I delete the 3rd requeriment
    Then I should see "La orden de servicio fue eliminada exitosamente"
    And I should see the following requeriments:
      |Client|Realization|Hour|Shipping company|Booking|Destiny|Rtype|
      |client 1|20/01/2011|08:30|shipping_company 1|booking 1|destiny 1|rtype 1|
      |client 2|20/01/2011|08:30|shipping_company 2|booking 2|destiny 2|rtype 2|
      |client 4|20/01/2011|08:30|shipping_company 4|booking 4|destiny 4|rtype 4|
```

When I run it, I get this error message

```
Using the default profile...
....................F--

(::) failed steps (::)

undefined method `type' for #<Requeriment:0x00000102796938> (ActionView::Template::Error)
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
./app/views/requeriments/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_requeriments_show_html_erb__801476454977741902_2168053700_3071000245049315254'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `block in render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `block in _render_template'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `_render_template'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:108:in `render_to_body'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:101:in `render_to_string'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:92:in `render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in `render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:435:in `_run__575588255767707561__process_action__2014970349567018671__callbacks'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/cucumber-rails-0.3.2/lib/cucumber/rails/action_controller.rb:13:in `process_action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in `process'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:103:in `optimized_each'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:353:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-test-0.5.7/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-test-0.5.7/lib/rack/test.rb:209:in `process_request'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-test-0.5.7/lib/rack/test.rb:57:in `get'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/session.rb:280:in `process_request'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/session.rb:119:in `request_page'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/elements/link.rb:20:in `click'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/scope.rb:276:in `click_link'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/methods.rb:7:in `click_link'
./features/step_definitions/requeriment_steps.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/session.rb:206:in `within'
/Users/forellana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/methods.rb:7:in `within'
./features/step_definitions/requeriment_steps.rb:7:in `/^I delete the (\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) requeriment$/'
features/manage_requeriments.feature:34:in `When I delete the 3rd requeriment'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/manage_requeriments.feature:27 # Scenario: Delete requeriment

2 scenarios (1 failed, 1 passed)
23 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped, 20 passed)
0m1.263s
```

But I don't have defined any type method, I don't know why webrat is triying to call it

my step definition is here

```
When /^I delete the (\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) requeriment$/ do |pos|
  visit requeriments_path
  within("table tr:nth-child(#{pos.to_i+1})") do
    click_link "Destroy"
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./app/views/requeriments/show.html.erb line 10 is where the error is. Do you have single-table inheritance? That's what this smells like.

Comment: there I was calling a type method that of course didn't exists